# Authenticate MVC client against self-hosted Web API (OWIN/Katana)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a Windows Service running a Web API hosted as a OWIN middleware - the server. The API uses application cookie authentication and validates users against a database, using OWINs identity model. Now I would like to authenticate a user who accesses the API through a standard MVC web application (the client), but I'm unsure how to achieve this, e.g. after I received a response along with the cookie from the API, where do I have to store it inside the MVC application so that the cookie will be automatically sent along with further API calls.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to.  Cookies are stored by the client's browser, and are sent to the web server with every request on the same domain name.  Each subdomain will have its own sandbox for cookies.  The main domain's cookies can be accessed by all subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

MVC application will store it in the users browser the cookie. If you need to find an alternate way to achieve it, why not try [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). You can then send the authorization token with every request header using your Ajax calls. If you are interested in an Angular Application, [here is an excellent tutorial that should help clarify a lot of question](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/).